# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I'm making an app where user can upload multiple photos, but they can upload one photo once. I want to append a background image as well as get the file_name value to set the value of the input. I wrote below algorithim but it has error of  Cannot use 'in' operator to search for..

This is the js

```
$.each('#photo_area div', function(i, obj) {
  i++;
  if (!obj.attr('style')) {
    obj.attr('style', 'background:url(' + data.result.filename + ') no-repeat center center');
    $('input[name="photos' + i + '"]').val(data.result.filename);

    return false;
  }
});
```

This is my DOM

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<input type="hidden" name="photo1">
<input type="hidden" name="photo2">
```

Comment: There's no use of the `in` operator in your code, but you are trying to call `.attr()` on a DOM element, which isn't going to work.

Comment: @squint The error is coming from inside the `$.each()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `$.each` incorrectly. The first argument to `$.each` must be an array or object, not a string. To iterate over a jquery collection, you use the `.each()` method, not `$.each.`.

And within the iteration function, `obj` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. To use jQuery methods, you have to use `$(obj)` or `$(this)`.

```
$("#photo_area div").each(function(i, obj) {
  i++;
  if (!$(obj).attr('style')) {
    $(obj).attr('style', 'background:url(' + data.result.filename + ') no-repeat center center');
    $('input[name="photos' + i + '"]').val(data.result.filename);

    return false;
  }
});
```

Returning `false` from the iteration function stops the loop. Is that what you want? So this will only update the first matching DIV that doesn't have a `style` attribute.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: obj.attr is not a function(anonymous function) @ edit:411n.extend.each

Comment: @Jennifer Thanks, I didn't notice the second use of `obj.attr` in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#photo_area div").each(function(i, obj) {
 i++;
 if (!$(obj).attr('style')) { // edited part
$(obj).attr('style', 'background:url(' +              data.result.filename + ') no-repeat center center');
$('input[name="photos' + i +             '"]').val(data.result.filename);

return false;
```

}
});

Use $(obj) instead of 'obj'